# getSymbols from alphaadvantage in R

Tags: r, quantmod

```
getSymbols.alphavantage('AMZN', from="2010-01-01", to=Sys.Date()-6, auto.assign=getOption('getSymbols.auto.assign', FALSE), api.key=api_key)
```

The will return the same data regardless of the "from" and "to" arguments. How do I fix this so that I get the data for dates that I want?

Answer (score 2):

When using alphavantage, you can either get the last 100 days of data or 20 years of data. There is no middle ground.

To get the 20 years of data output.size needs to be set to "full". See below.

```
amzn_av <- getSymbols.alphavantage('AMZN', 
                                auto.assign=FALSE, 
                                api.key=api_key,
                                output.size = "full") # default compact => 100 days

str(amzn_av)
An ‘xts’ object on 2000-03-20/2020-03-20 containing:
  Data: num [1:5033, 1:5] 63.5 65.1 70.9 69.5 67.7 ...
```

If you want to be able to specify the period, you could use tiingo:

```
amzn_tiingo <- getSymbols.tiingo('AMZN', 
                                 from = "2010-01-01", 
                                 to = Sys.Date()-6, 
                                 auto.assign = FALSE, 
                                 api.key = api_tiingo)

str(amzn_tiingo)
An ‘xts’ object on 2010-01-04/2020-03-13 containing:
  Data: num [1:2566, 1:5] 136 133 135 132 131 ...
```

Do note that you can just use `getSymbols` but in the `source` option specify "av" or "tiingo".